# Removing duplicate entries and replacing it with comma | Bash

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file which contains ip address and port number in this order:

ipaddress : port

**1.1.1.1:21 

1.1.1.1:22 

2.2.2.2:443 

3.3.3.3:80 

3.3.3.3:443**

I need Result in this below format 
  
ipaddress : port, port

**1.1.1.1:21,22 

2.2.2.2:443 

3.3.3.3:80,443**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no trailing spaces on the lines in the input file:

```
$ awk -F ':' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 in ports { ports[$1] = ports[$1] "," $2; next } { ports[$1] = $2 } END { for (ip in ports) print ip, ports[ip] }' file
3.3.3.3:80,443
1.1.1.1:21,22
2.2.2.2:443
```

The `awk` script,

```
BEGIN       { OFS=FS }
$1 in ports { ports[$1] = ports[$1] "," $2; next }
            { ports[$1] = $2 }
END         { for (ip in ports) print ip, ports[ip] }
```

would first set the output field separator to be the same as the input field separator, which is a `:` character (this is given on the command line with `-F ':'`), then it would test whether the current first field (the IP address) is a key in the `ports` array.  If it is, the port number (the second field) is added with a comma as a delimiter to that array entry.  If it's not, the entry in the array is simply set to the port number for that IP address.

At the end, all stored IP addresses are printed with their collected port numbers.

Answer (score 2):

With [GNU Datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
datamash -t: -s groupby 1 collapse 2 < file
```

If your data are already sorted, you can omit the `-s` .

---

Or using an anonymous array inside a hash in Perl:

```
$ perl -F: -lne '
    push @{ $h{$F[0]} }, $F[1] 
    }{ 
    for $k (sort keys %h) {print "$k:", join ",", @{ $h{$k}} }
' file
1.1.1.1:21,22
2.2.2.2:443
3.3.3.3:80,443
```

Answer (score 0):

using miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) is

```
mlr --nidx --fs ':' nest --implode --values --across-records --nested-fs "," -f 2 input
```

it gives you back

```
1.1.1.1:21,22
2.2.2.2:443
3.3.3.3:80,443
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

```
for i in `awk -F ":" '{print $1}' filename| sort | uniq`; do awk -F ":" -v i="$i" '$1 == i{print i,$2}' l.txt| s '/^$/d'| awk '{if (!seen[$1]++ )print }'| tr "\n" ","| sed "s/,/ /" ;done
```

output

```
1.1.1.1 21,22
2.2.2.2 443
3.3.3.3 80,443
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using the `sed`  editor. There we maintain 2 lines at any time in the pattern space and look for changes in the IP number. So long as we continue getting the same IP, we remove from the 2nd portion the IP and join it with the 1st portion with a comma. If not, then that means an IP change has been detected and we promptly print the first portion only, remove it from the pattern space, and go back and read in the next IP line into the pattern space and repeat the same checks.

```
$ sed -e '
    :loop
       $!N
       s/^\(\([^:]*:\).*[^[:space:]]\).*\n\2/\1,/
    tloop
    P;D
 ' input-file.txt

 1.1.1.1:21,22
 2.2.2.2:443 
 3.3.3.3:80,443

 $ perl -lne '
    my($ip, $port) = /(\H+):(\H+)/;
    push @seen, $ip if ! exists $h{$ip};
    push @{$h{$ip}}, $port;}{
    print $_,  ":", join ",", @{$h{$_}} for @seen;
 ' input-file.txt
```

With Perl we can do the same by means of a hash which will maintain the IPs as it's keys and an array ref as the values comprising the  ports. Also, we ensure to not  consider any trailing blanks. The array @seen maintains the IPs in the order they were seen.